# Date command in Bash

Tags: bash, date

How do I call the date +%a command in an if statement in bash? I've searched around google but can't find anything. I'm trying to create a script so that if date +%a presents Mon I echo Backup your files!

So far I've tried this:

```
if [date +%a==Mon]
then
echo back
fi
```

Among other variations.

What am i missing?

I apologize in advance if this a dumb question, I'm new to Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
if [[ $(date +%a) == Mon ]] ; then
   echo Backup time
fi
```

Comment: So the $(date + %a) forces bash to consider date + %a as its return?

Comment: `$(command)` is substituted by the output of the command. See *Command substitution* in `man bash`.